# Heroku Redis Upgrade Required?

Tags: heroku, memory, redis, sidekiq

My heroku sidekiq worker logs constantly has the following message:

```
pid=4 tid=nu8 WARN: Your Redis network connection is performing extremely poorly.
Last RTT readings were [203500, 200354, 315449, 310440, 204357], ideally these should be < 1000.
Ensure Redis is running in the same AZ or datacenter as Sidekiq.
```

Would upgrading my Redis add-on from the free Hobby tier improve this or is there just some memory optimization I should be focused on? What metrics help indicate that I should be upgrading from the Hobby tier for Redis on Heroku?

Comment: What did Heroku say when you contacted them?

Comment: @markw I'm getting the same error message... any luck?

Comment: @ToddT I ended up solving this by making my workers process much smaller batches instead and this message went away. Separately, we've also scaled up the redis and I haven't seen these messages since! I followed the documentation to upgrade and just note the TLS requirements https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#upgrading-a-heroku-redis-instance